# Regex: Find the letter (diacritics/Accent Marks) "î" in the middle of the words, but not the letter î at the beginning or at the end of the words

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I must find the letter (diacritics/Accent Marks) `î` in the middle of the words, but not the letter `î` at the beginning or at the end of the words.

For example:

1.`stăpînii`

2.`înstăpanit`

3.`coborî`

4.`înfornît`

So the regex must find the letter `î` just from words like the first one: `stăpînii`.

The 2 and 3 word have the letter `î` at the beginnind or at the end. So those must be ignore from finding.

The 4 case is tricky. It starts with `î` and also has an `î` in the middle. So, only the second `î` must be find by regex.

**FINAL:** Regex must find the letter `î`from the first word `stăpînii` and also must find the second `î` from the last word `înfornît`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to work with lookahead and lookbehind here:

```
(?<=\w)î(?=\w)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\w)î(?=\w)  
(?<=  )         #positive lookbehind, "must be preceeding the match"
    \w     \w   #match any word character
       î        #character to match
        (?=  )  #positive lookahed, "must be following the match"
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/7PKHDj/1)

Comment: Fixed, had the wrong regex flair selected

Comment: thanks , works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Much more efficient than lookaround, use non word-boundary, it reduces the step number by 2.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\Bî\B`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\B          # NON word-boundary, make sure we have a word character before
î           # letter î
\B          # NON word-boundary, make sure we have a word character after
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, toto. I didn't know about this ;)

Answer (score 1):

For Notepad++, use `(?<!\<)î(?!\>)`

- `(?<!...)` - negative lookbehind (i.e: preceeding text doesn't match)

  - `\<` - start of word boundary (regex extension)
- `(?!...)` - negative lookahead (i.e: following text doesn't match)

  - `\>` - end of word boundary (regex extension)

Comment: thanks , works ;)